# AdMob Plugin - How to Implement Interstitial First and Then Html Page

Tags: javascript, interstitial, cordova-admob, phonegap-admob

I am developing one Cordova app with floatinghotpot AdMobpro plugin.
The app has these codes:

index.html

```
<a href=“mainpage.html" id="btn_prepare" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">GO TO APP</a>
```

in the admobshow.js, I have these snippets:

```
$('#btn_prepare').click(function(){
  AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
    adId:admobid.interstitial,    

  });

         AdMob.showInterstitial();
       window.open($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

(The code is taken from here: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/blob/master/test/index.html

I want this to happen:
1.) User clicks Go To APP and the plugin shows Interstitial.
2.) When the User dismisses the interstitial, the mainpage.html should open.

But, what is now happening is:
1.) the mainpage.html opens first and then the interstitial is shown in a few seconds.

I want the mainpage.html to be shown only after the interstitial is shown. (Or when the interstitial is acted upon.) I don't want the mainpage.html to be shown automatically.

Can someone help me how to tweak the above code?

Comment: This pic from Google describes what I want: https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/91E0E29ADFA1A1BF42097E0699CC491BE874

Answer (score 1):

You need the code that prepares the interstitial `AdMob.prepareInterstitial` to be called some time before the user clicks that button. The plugin needs some time preparing it, so it can't immediately show it when you call `AdMob.showInterstitial()`.

Just prepare the interstitial when the user enters the page for example.

Comment: My code is working. There is no problem in AdMob.prepareInterstitial or in AdMob.showInterstitial(). The issue is: the interstitial appears but it comes up after the loading of mainpage.html, but, I want the Interstitial to load first. And the mainpage.html should come up later.

Answer (score 1):

See response in this question for some code and ideas on how to implement:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31187541/4025963

**EDIT**

Assuming [cordova-admob](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova) plugin, basically the idea could be this one:

```
<a onclick="showInterstitial()" id="btn_prepare" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">GO TO APP</a>
```

And in your js code:

```
var isAppForeground = true;
var isShowMainOnCloseAd = false;
var isMainAlreadyShown = false;
var isInterstitialAvailable = false;    

function showInterstitial() {
  if (isInterstitialAvailable) {
    admob.showInterstitialAd();
  } else {
    showMain(function () {
      isMainAlreadyShown = true;
    });
  }
}

function initAds() {
  if (admob) {
    var adPublisherIds = {
      ios : {
        banner : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
        interstitial : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII"
      },
      android : {
        banner : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
        interstitial : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII"
      }
    };

    var admobid = (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? adPublisherIds.android : adPublisherIds.ios;

    admob.setOptions({
      publisherId:          admobid.banner,
      interstitialAdId:     admobid.interstitial,
      autoShowInterstitial: false
    });

    registerAdEvents();

  } else {
    alert('cordova-admob plugin not ready');
  }
}

function onAdLoaded(e) {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
      isInterstitialAvailable = true;
    }
  }
}

function onAdOpened(e) {
  if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL && !isMainAlreadyShown) {
    isShowMainOnCloseAd = true;
  }
}

function onAdClosed(e) {
  if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL && isShowMainOnCloseAd) {
    isShowMainOnCloseAd = false;
    if (!isMainAlreadyShown) {
      showMain(function () {
        isMainAlreadyShown = true;
      });
    }
  }
}

function onPause() {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    isAppForeground = false;
  }
}

function onResume() {
  if (!isAppForeground) {
    setTimeout(admob.requestInterstitialAd, 1);
    isAppForeground = true;
  }
}

function registerAdEvents() {
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLoaded, onAdLoaded);
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdOpened, onAdOpened);
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdClosed, onAdClosed);

  document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
  document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
  initAds();

  // request an interstitial
  admob.requestInterstitialAd();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: I think I have not stated my issue properly. To paraphrase, 1.) I have been able to implement AdMob interstitial successfully, as shown in my codes stated previously. They are working. 2.) My problem is with the order of appearance;  html page coming up before interstitial instead of appearing later. 3.) Can someone give me a working JS code of Interstitial first and then html page?

Comment: You could use admob events, see [cordova-admob plugin wiki](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Events#admobeventsonadclosed). In the referenced question you can see how to use events

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but, sadly, this does not solve the issue. I am able to implement Interstitials, so, no problem over there. My code : <a href=“mainpage.html" id="btn_prepare" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">GO TO APP</a> . On pressing the button, I want the Interstitial to come up first, and later mainpage.html. Right now, the mainpage.html comes up first and then Interstitial. How do I reverse the order?

Comment: change the `<a href="mainpage.html" ...` by `<a onclick="showInterstitial()" ...` and then implement the interstitial flow there. You should be sure that an interstitial is available with `onAdLoaded()` event listener.

Comment: See changes in response